# tinymce text editors tiny_mce_popup.js not effecting in chrome

Tags: javascript, tinymce

tinymce  tiny_mce_popup.js not effecting in chrome.It works fine in firefox. in chrome after image upload below timymce popup script not working

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false,@insertString);

tinyMCEPopup.close();
```

also getting js error
 Getting js error in tin_mce_popup.js line 5               Uncayght TypeError: cannot read property 'EditorManager' of undefined

also I am getting another js error "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "URL1" from frame with URL "URL2". Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: yes.. Getting js error in tin_mce_popup.js line 5               Uncayght TypeError: cannot read property 'EditorManager' of undefined

Comment: no I didn't initialise editor. Please help me. where I intialize editor? First time I am using tinymce

Comment: d'oh, have a look at the tinymce FAQ to get started: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ

Comment: Oh.. This is initialize?       
           
tinyMCE.init({ }) I did and works fine in firebox. js error only in chrome

Comment: yepp, although there is the possibility to initialize an editor using tinymce.execCommand to do so too

Comment: also I am getting another js error  "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "URL1" from frame with URL "URL2". Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: this happens when your domain between several frames is not the same